# Python GUI with background disappearing when mouse hoover

Tags: python, wxpython, pyinstaller, cefpython

I have a weird bug on my python3.7 application and I don't have a clue on how to solve it.

**Application description:** Executable bundled with Pyinstaller which consists in a Flask server and a CEFPython browser that renders a react build. Relevant packacges: wx, cefpython3

**Bug description:** Everything works fine until black squares starts to appearing and disappearing with mouse hoovering, replacing the background of the CEFPython window. Image attached[image]

**Notes:** I believe this might be some incompatibility between python packages as I've made some updates of the packages before this bug starts to happen. However, I don't know where to start and cannot reproduce this bug consistently on my laptop which is very annoying. 100% times this happen was on production environment (.exe) and never happened on development.

**Specs of the laptop where the bug is more evident:** Intel Core i5 CPU M520@2.40Ghz, 4GB RAM, Windows 10 x64

Comment: I've come across something similar in my own code but that was caused by menus being rebuilt, while they were still displayed. The result was blank areas. I've no idea if this is the same type of thing but you should be able to pin the result down to some common event prior to it happening. You don't say if the code is yours or if you have access to it, but you do have a common event, mouse hovering, so start there, what else can occur at the same time?

Comment: Hello, yes the code is mine and I have several users using it. This strange event it is not related with mouse hoovering events (because i dont have any). Only when these black squares appear, the amount and localization of the black squares vary when the mouse is moved. I know this because it happened one time to me (And many many times with other users). Unfortunetly, I dont know how to replicate consistently...

Comment: Mouse events, motion events? Also have a look at whatever it is, that you use to generate the .exe, if it never occurs with a straight execution by python.